# How to prevent an application from making an upgrade?

Tags: package-management, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to forbid updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-forbid-updating-of-a-specific-package)

How to force an application to stay on the same current version?

For instance, I don't want the application to ask for an upgrade in the update manager, (I know that I can un-check it) but I don't want it to show up.

Answer (score 1):

### With aptitude (terminal)

Use `sudo aptitude hold packagename`, i.e. `sudo aptitude hold apache2`. To undo do `sudo aptitude unhold package_name`.

Also see [How to prevent a package from being updated in Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-prevent-a-package-from-being-updated-in-ubuntu.html) for more ways of achieving this.

### In synaptic (GUI)

1. Open Synaptic Package Manager (System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager if you use gnome).
2. Click search button and type the package name you want to hold.
3. When you find package select it and go to Package (in menu) and click Lock Version.

As described by [Re: Disable Package Upgrade](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=2372955&postcount=2) and [How To Disable Package From Updating In Ubuntu](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/11/how-to-disable-package-from-updating-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the command "aptitude" already stated you may use The Synaptic Package Manager to "lock" a package. Simply select the package you want held, then select Package>Lock Version.